# Slicer to search for a specific string in a column - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables.

*Table1*

```
Category 
A
B
...
```

*Table2*

```
Companies | Indistries
1         | A,D,X
2         | Z,B,X
3         | N,D,R,B,Q
```

I would like to have a slicer with different categories (A-Z). When clicking A all Diagrams should be filtered according to the Companies that "contain" industry A.

Long story short: it would be like a normal relationship but instead of finding the same, it would be a "contains".

Thank you for your help! Really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have relation between Table1 and Table2? Slicer is single select enabled? or Multiple value can be selected from the slicer?

Comment: There is no relationship since table 1 are just the categories and in table 2 they are listed in one cell (--> I wouldnt know how I could link them). 
For the slicer it would be great if multiple values could be selected (--> multible categories).

Comment: So far everything as it is required. Last question, in table2- do comma separated categories are in asscending order? Or they can be in any random order?

Comment: Random order and also not a fixed number (can vary from 1-18 categories)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have removed my previous answer and added a new answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please down load the sample report file from link - [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zZUcvButIoMQt3j6Ogb1NBNLkCoUd9im/view?usp=sharing)

Follow-

1. Created a Index column in table **your_table_name**
2. Created a new table **slicer_new** with this below code-

```
let
    Source = your_table_name,
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Indistries", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Indistries.1", "Indistries.2", "Indistries.3", "Indistries.4"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Indistries.1", type text}, {"Indistries.2", type text}, {"Indistries.3", type text}, {"Indistries.4", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here below is the final output of **slicer_new** table-

[image]

3. Get back to report and check the relation between table **your_table_name** and **slicer_new**.
4. Create slicer from table **slicer_new**
5. Add table visual for column **Indistries** from table **your_table_name**
6. Now select value in slicer, everything should work as expected now.

Comment: It's amazing that some people are just here to help! 
Thank you very much... Highly appreciated!